# InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to spoof a mouse event in Javascript. Here's whats happening:

```
// Create event object
var event = new CustomEvent('mousedown');
    
// Initialize
event.initCustomEvent('mousedown', true, false, {});

// Inherit
event = Object.create(event);
event.pageX = 10;
event.pageY = 10;
```

Now, to dispatch...

```
targetElement.dispatchEvent(event);
```

When I do this I get the error:

> Error: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': The event provided is null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

An *event* must have an **own property** of *type*, an inherited *type* property is not enough and will mean *type* is treated as *undefined*, hence the error

```
// Create event object
var event = new CustomEvent('mousedown', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false});

// initCustomEvent deprecated, see below

// Inherit
event = Object.create(event);
event.type = 'mousedown';
event.pageX = 10;
event.pageY = 10;
```

This error may also be a warning of other unexpected behaviour that will stem from the way you're dispatching an *Object* which is inheriting from an *Event* rather than having own properties.

*CustomEvent* instances are not sealed, so you can always add properties to them directly

```
var ev = new CustomEvent('mousedown', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false});
ev.pageX = 10;
ev.pageY = 10;
```

---

Be aware that the [`customEvent.initCustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/initCustomEvent) method is **deprecated**, you should pass this information into the constructor as a dictionary in the second arg,

```
var cev = new CustomEvent('mousedown', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false});
```

If you don't need a *detail* property, consider using *Event* instead of *CustomEvent*

```
var eev = new Event('mousedown', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false});
// cev as above, now consider
'detail' in cev; // true
cev.detail; // null
// vs
'detail' in eev; // false
eev.detail; // undefined
```

A *mousedown* event usually has a *read-only* detail of `0` (which rarely gets checked by code)

Comment: `pageX` and `pageY` are read-only for `CustomEvent` instances as well.

Comment: @dopatraman they're not read-only on _CustomEvent_ instances even after dispatch, `document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.pageX = 10;
    console.log(e.pageX);
});` followed by `document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('mousedown', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false}));` will log `10`

Comment: They are readonly in _MouseEvent_ instances though, which is why I didn't suggest `new MouseEvent(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
event = Object.create(event);
```

Apparently, `dispatchEvent` expects event object to have certain *own* properties which it fails to find, because it's not checking prototype. Then it assumes that passed object is not well-formed event instance. Hence the error.

I'm not sure why you want to create new object with original event in prototype, without this everything should work.

Comment: I need to inherit from the event obj because `pageX` and `pageY` are read-only properties.